# AG-Grid Pivot Table Totals Field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pivot, ag-grid, finance

I have a use case where I need to add a Totals field to a pivot table. This Totals field should have the Total for the row group in it. So in this case for 2008 it would be 4 gold and coincidentally for 2012 it would also be 4 gold.

For some reason it seems exceptionally complex to create a "fake" column in a pivot table in AG Grid. If I can make a "fake" column called "Totals" I can map through each row in my renderer and paint the totals on each line, but it is not immediately obvious how to achieve this in the API.

While I was expecting an API function to exist such that I can have a totals field at the very end and it would calculate it based on the pivot value automatically, I am willing to work around that limitation/absent feature. I am advised that this is a common functionality in pivot tables so I am a bit surprised how difficult this requirement is.

Edit: To confirm, I need a totals "field" in this pivot table, not a totals row at the bottom. Such that I can see the totals per row, not per column.

[image: Pivot Table]

Answer (score 0):

set the property `groupIncludeTotalFooter` to true in your grid options which should show you totals at the bottom of your pivot table.

`groupIncludeTotalFooter={true}`

[Working Example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/ag-grid-packages-forked-7rz8q9?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrt3o1f90006356ip8zab3gx%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrt3o1f80002356ixa8xmwp7%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrt3o1f80003356imy4mowsx%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrt3o1f80005356ifnoma77k%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clrt3o1f80002356ixa8xmwp7%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrt3o1f80001356i5wlesrqf%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Findex.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrt3o1f80002356ixa8xmwp7%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrt3o1f80001356i5wlesrqf%2522%257D%252C%2522clrt3o1f80005356ifnoma77k%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrt3o1f80004356idt0sbpq1%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrt3o1f80005356ifnoma77k%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrt3o1f80004356idt0sbpq1%2522%257D%252C%2522clrt3o1f80003356imy4mowsx%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrt3o1f80003356imy4mowsx%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D).

[Documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grouping-footers/).

Comment: Hello, this does not solve my problem. This adds a totals amount at the bottom which would advise me the total of metals that each entity has individually. So it would tell me Usain has 6 and the other individuals have 1.

I may have not been clear, I need a total on the far right to communicate that the entities had 4 gold in 2008 and 4 gold in 2012.